# Select a function in a Pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have the following vars:

```
x
y
```

and functions:

```
def runx(x):
    print(x)

def runy(y):
    print (y)

def runxy(x, y):
    print(x + y)

def nonexy():
    print('none')
```

What's the Pythonic way to choose a function based on the next requirements:

-If `value` is only greater than `y` run the func `runy`

-If `value` is only greater than `x` run the func `runx`

-If `value` is greater than both `x` and `y` run the func `runxy`

-If `value` is not greather than `x` and `y` runt the func `nonexy`

`value`, `x`, `y` could be any number

Example:

```
x = 4
y = 6
value = 5
```

Here `value` is only greater than `x`, so run `runx(x)`

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: i tried to represent in a some way the functionality i need to put in a class, i need to validate if a value is great than two variables of none to correctly choose a method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach that is often forgotten is the use of logic tables. Now, while I'm *not* arguing that this is the best approach here, I consider it interesting so here goes - take or leave what you will.

```
             value > y   value <= y
             ----------  ----------
value > x  | runxy       runx
value <= x | runy        nonex
```

Then we can codify it as so, utilizing the fact that functions are first-class values:

```
arr = [[runxy, runx], [runy, nonex]]
```

And access it as so:

```
col = 0 if value > y else 1
row = 0 if value > x else 1
fn = arr[row][col]
```

Then just edit the current design such *all* the functions should take x and y parameters (or use wrapping lambdas in the above table) and..

```
fn(x, y)
```

Comment: Credit for being slick, though probably a bit overkill for a four-value problem :p

Comment: `fn = ([nonexy, runy], [runx, runxy])[value > x][value > y]`

Answer (score 7):

```
if value > y :
    if value > x :
        runxy(x, y)
    else :
        runy(y)
else :
    if value > x :
        runx(x)
    else :
        nonexy()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope. Depending on if you need return values you could condense the inner statements to ``return runxy(x,y) if value > x else runy(y)`` etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
if value > y and value <= x:
    runy(y)
elif value <= y and value > x:
    runx(x)
elif value > x and value > y:
    runxy(x, y)
else:
    nonexy()
```

There's no real good way to handle this kind of pattern but to just write out the if/else block.

Comment: @ErikAllik: I think so. It certainly isn't Hasthon!

Comment: @acomar: Don't forget that `else if` is spelled `elif` in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Even more overkill than other answers, but might be interesting for someone:

```
def fn_picker(value, x, y):
    functions = { # lambdas to make it shorter
        0: lambda kwargs: 'none',
        1: lambda kwargs: kwargs['x'],
        2: lambda kwargs: kwargs['y'],
        3: lambda kwargs: kwargs['x'] + kwargs['y']
    }
    key = sum([(value > x), (value > y)*2]) # True is 1, False is 0
    fn = functions[key]
    return fn(locals())

print(fn_picker(5, 4, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the functions take x,y as parameters, you could use:

```
(nonexy,runx,runy,runxy)[1*(x<=value<=y)+2*(y<=value<=x)+3*(x<value>y)](x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

We define a dictionary, which maps a boolean-pair to a lambda expression. 
The boolean-pair is a two-tuple, representing the function-selecting criteria. 
The lambda expression wraps a function. It takes x y, and calls the function
with the parameters it needs.

Now, we can define a function which combines the tools we defined above.

```
mapping = {
    (True, True): lambda x,y: runxy(x,y),
    (True, False): lambda x,y: runx(x),
    (False, True): lambda x,y: runy(y),
    (False, False): lambda x,y: nonexy()
}

def f(x, y, value):
    mapping[value > x, value > y](x,y)
```

Note that it is enough to define `mapping` only once, regardless how many times we want to run the task. This is why we put it outside `f`. (No need to define it each time the task is run.)